# Mongodb DB query to compare the data from two collections and get the results if data is same

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections data like below . I need compare the two collections data and get the data if the data is same  . Tried with below query but is it not giving any results .I am new to mongodb query ,Can anyone help me how to get the code key values  if the data is same in both collections .The query is not returning any errors but the code values are not getting populated to new cllection

```
**Collection 1:**

    {
        "_id" : {
            "value" : "12345"
        },
       "value" : {
            "Identifier" : "12345",
            "statu" : "simple",
            
             "code" : {
            "key" : "US",
            "value" : "United State of America"
          },
        "Code" : {
            "key" : "UK",
            "value" : "London"
        }
    }
    
    **Collection 2** :
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("12345"),
        
        "value" : {
            "Identifier" : "12345",
            "statu" : "simple",
            
             "code" : {
            "key" : "US",
            "value" : "United State of America"
          },
        "Code" : {
            "key" : "UK",
            "value" : "London"
        }
           
        },
        
    }
     Mongo DB :
    
    
    var identifiers = db.getSiblingDB("Datbase").getCollection("Collection1").find({
        $or:[
                {'code':{$exists:true}},
                {'Code1':{$exists:true}},
                
            ]
    }).toArray()
    var bulk = db.getSiblingDB("Database2").getCollection("Collection2").initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
    
    identifiers.forEach(Identifier =>{
                 db.getSiblingDB("Database2").getCollection("Collection2").aggregate([
                {
                    $match:{
                         "Identifier":'$Identifier',
                        
                    }
                },
               {
                "$group" : {
                    "_id" : {
                        "Identifier":'$Identifier',
                        "key" : "$code.key",
                        "value" : "$code.value",
                        "key1" : "$code1.key1",
                        "value1" : "$code1.value2",
                       
                    }
                }
            }, {
            $merge:{
                        into:{
                            db:'Database',
                            coll:'Collection'
                        }
                    }
            
            }
               
                ])
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using cursor get one by one items from 1st collection
2. For every item from 1st collection query 2nd collection for existense
3. If item does not exist or it's body is different ([Use `lodash.isEqual` method](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual)) push them to some array or use `replaceOne` method to insert or replace document. (install lodash: `npm i --save lodash`)

```js
const _ = require('lodash'); // import it at top


(async () => { // You can remove it if Your code already inside async scope

const source = db.getSiblingDB("Datbase").getCollection("Collection1");
const destination = db.getSiblingDB("Datbase").getCollection("Collection2");

const query = {$or:[
  {'code':{$exists:true}},
  {'Code1':{$exists:true}},            
]};
const cursor = await source.find(query);

const differentItems = [];

// iterating source collection items
while(await cursor.hasNext()) {
  const src = await cursor.next(); // source collectio inem
  
  const queryDestination = {
    "Identifier": src.Identifier,  // extend Your equality constrains here
  };
  const dest = await destination.findOne(queryDestination); 
  
  // it may not exist || may be different (not equal)
  const isDifferent = !dest || !(
    _.isEqual(
      _.omit(src, ['_id']),
      _.omit(dest, ['_id'])
    )
  );

  if (isDifferent) {
    differentItems.push({src, dest});

    /* or replace in db
    await destination.replaceOne(
      queryDestination, 
      _.omit(src, ['_id']),
      {
        upsert: true,
      }
    );
    */
  } 
}

console.log(`found ${differentItems.length} different documments`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(differentItems, null, 4));

)();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response .I think the above code is based on nodejs and it is giving syntax errors .It would be good if the code base is in mongoshell for me to understand

Comment: @Rose if You want to update documents from source to destination collection You can just do upsert. Otherwise You've to be concrete with fields which You want to compare, cause I don't think mongodb does deep comparison

Comment: ,Update the documents is not required , if the key values are matching ,need to pull the data based on Identifier .Here in my script ,I am trying to with the match operator if in both  collections Identifiers are same and then look up the data for code key values ,in case if both are same ,writing to new collection .My script is not returning the errors but it is not giving any results . Need help here